# Is Remote Desktop disabled by default on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Is remote desktop disabled on default on windows 7 desktop?
How would remote desktop take place for anonymous person to get into my system?
Do they need my router credentials in order to get in?

Comment: Yes it is disabled. You need to turn it on. They will need the computer's password/username (domain?). The router just 'forwards' the request on, so typically there is no access to the router (until you've logged onto a machine). -1 for no research effort

Comment: @DaveRook: From the question pattern it sure seems to me that [avsdvsdd](http://superuser.com/users/204350/avsdvsdd) = [jsldfjskaldfsdf](http://superuser.com/users/203233/jsldfjskaldfsdf), so the lack of research effort and general confusion about basic concepts is not surprising.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is disabled by default (and I believe only available on versions higher than Windows Home Premium, @ least that was the case w/ XP), and it has to be enabled on your windows firewall and under Control Panel, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/) for more info. Your router if you have one will also have to allow port 3389 through, or whatever port you choose but 3389 is the default, and the person will need the credentials of an account that can login to that workstation.

Comment: Port 3389 only works if the PC port is also 3389. However, you can use port forwarding and forward to local IP. I also never had to fiddle with the Firewall settings on W7

Comment: Credentials of an account meaning Windows credentials or router credentials?

Comment: Credentials for a Windows user account.